# Знаки препинания в устоявшихся выражениях

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в пословице "Если нельзя, но очень хочется — значит, можно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Обычно это выражение имеет такой вид: ***Если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно.***

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/68888214

В нем нет подчеркнутой паузы, она здесь не нужна.

2) Другой вариант записи: ***Если нельзя, но очень хочется — значит, можно.***

Тире здесь скорее интонационное, так как в этой редакции требуется деление предложения на две части, иначе смысл трудно понять.

В общем же случае мы имеем двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ, где постановка тире не требуется, например: *Если (раз) вы читаете это мое письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул...*

Но в БСП тире ставится: *Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит.*

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220